# How can I use toString() to pring a linked list of integers in Java?

Tags: java, list, tostring

I am currently creating a program to print a linked list of random integers using a toString() method. However, as it is, my program has no errors but will not print anything. I have a feeling that the error may be linked to the val != null statement in toString(), but I am super new to toString() and linked lists, so I can't say for sure. Why doesn't my program print a linked list?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;
public class IntList {
    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node next;
    }
    private Node head;

    public IntList(int n) {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(rand.nextInt(n));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for(IntList.Node val = head; val != null; val = val.next) {
            result += val.value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntList list = new IntList(6);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

If the error is somewhere else and not in toString(), please let me know and I will try to find it!

Answer (score 0):

You do not add node to your IntList in your constructor. You head is initialized with null so there is nothing to print.

Extend your constructor with something like this.

```java
public IntList(int n) {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(rand.nextInt(n));
        }
        //Init head
        this.head = new Node(list.get(0),null); //Add constructor to the Node
        // Append all the elements from the list.
        for(int i : list){
        Node lastNode = head;
        while(lastNode.getNext() != null){ 
           lastNode = lastNode.getNext(); 
        }
        lastNode.setNext( new Node(i,null));
        }
    }
```